# PyQt5: Python crash when using QWebEngineView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am developing an application in Mac OS using PyQt5. I now try to port it to Windows 7. My application uses QWebEngineView. The following is the class that use QWebEngineView:

```
class HTMLRenderer(QWebEngineView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ....
```

When I open the xml file that describes the problem, it reads:

```
<ProblemSignatures>
    <EventType>BEX64</EventType>
....
```

BEX64 means Buffer overflow.

But Python has stopped working. But it works fine in Mac OS. It seems that QWebEngineView cannot be used on Windows 7. How do I solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I am pretty sure `QWebEngineView` works on Windows. Can you try any of the C++ based examples that came with your Qt installation?

Comment: Hi, I now manage to get it to work on Windows. But now there is a new problem. I call setHtml(....) and then call show(). But the web view is now blank. Thank you.